# Do we really need the app server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, iis-7

I'm about to start writing a web app (Asp.Net/IIS7) which will be accessible over the internet. It will be placed behind a firewall which accepts http and https.

The previous system which we are going to replace doesn't let this web server talk directly to a database, but rather have it making highly specialized web service calls (through a new firewall which only allows this kind of calls) to a separate app server which then go to the DB to operate on the data.

I have worked on many systems in my day, but this is the first one which has taken security this seriously. Is this a common setup? My first thought was to use Windows Authentication in the connectionstring on the web server and have the user be a crippled DB-user (can only view and update its own data) and then allow DB access through the inner firewall as well.

Am I Naïve? Seems like I will have to do a lot of mapping of data if we use the current setup for the new system.

Edit: The domain of this app is online ordering of goods (Business to business), Users (businesses) log in, input what they can deliver at any given time period, view previous transaction history, view projected demand for goods etc. No actual money is exchanged through this system, but this system provides the information on which goods are available for sale, which is data input to the ordering system

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some insight into the sensitivity of the data in the solution that you are trying to protect and what the client's requirements are. Higher security usually comes at a higher cost. There is a difference between a banking transaction web site with thousands of users and an just-for-fun application where you and your buddies can vote for which pub to visit on the weekend.

Comment: This 3 level architecture is not just for security. Another reason it may have been used is for a SOA solution. So that if a new systems comes along that also needs to access the DB via code it can reuse the same Service layer

Comment: Added domain description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of arrangement (DMZ with web server, communicating through firewall with app server, communicating through firewall with db) is very common in certain types of environment, especially in large transactional systems (online corporate banking, for example)

There are very good security reasons for doing this, the main one being that it will slow down an attack on your systems. The traditional term for it is Defence in Depth (or Defense if you are over that side of the water)

**Reasonable security assumption**: your webserver will be continually under attack

So you stick it in a DMZ and limit the types of connection it can make by using a firewall. You also limit the webserver to just being a web server - this reduces the number of possible attacks (the attack surface)

**2nd reasonable security assumption**: at some point a zero-day exploit will be found that will get to your web server and allow it to be compromised, which could lead to to an attack on your user/customer database

So you have a firewall limiting the number of connections to the application server.

**3rd reasonable security assumption**: zero-days will be found for the app server, but the odds of finding zero-days for the web and app servers at the same time are reduced dramatically if you patch regularly.

So if the value of your data/transactions is high enough, adding that extra layer could be essential to protect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

We have an app that is configured similarly.  The interface layer lives on a web server in the DMZ, the DAL is on a server inside the firewall with a web service bridging the gap between them.  In conjunction with this we have an authorization manager inside the firewall which exposes another web service that is used to control what users are allowed to see and do within the app.  This app in one of our main client data tracking systems, and is accessible to our internal employees and outside contractors.  It also deals with medical information so it falls under the HIPAA rules.  So while I don’t think this set up is particularly common it is not unheard of, particularly with highly sensitive data or in situations where you have to deal with audits by a regulatory body.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonably scalable, reasonably secure, conventional web application is going to abstract the database away from the web machine using one or more service and caching tiers. SQL injection is one of the leading vectors for penetration/hacking/cracking, and databases often tend to be one of the more complex, expensive pieces of the overall architecture/TOC. Using services tiers allows you to move logic out of the DB, to employ out-of-process caching, to shield the DB from injection attempts, etc. etc. You get better, cheaper, more secure performance this way. It also allows for greater flexibility when it comes to upgrades, redundancy or maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

Configuring the user's access rights seems like a more robust solution to me. Also your DataAccess layer should have some security built in, too. Adding this additional layer could end up being a performance hit but it really depends on what mechanism you're using to move data from "WebServer1" to "WebServer2." Without more specific information in that regard, it's not possible to give a more solid answer.

Comment: Easier but certainly not more robust.